# Sales Tax Exemption for an Authorized User?

Tags: 8, commerce

I have my Drupal Commerce store set up to apply my state sales tax on appropriate purchases. I also have an authorized user who has a state-approved sales tax exemption. I'm trying to configure my tax type such that no sales tax will be applied on their orders, but I'm not having much luck.

I've installed the Commerce Product Tax Conditions module, which appears to support a customer role condition. The module documentation doesn't identify that condition as "apply sales tax for this role" or "exempt this role from sales tax", though, and I haven't been able to apply an exemption.

How can I make this work?

Comment: Did you try checkmarking all the roles except the one you don't want to be taxed?

Answer (score 0):

After looking at the code I figured out that this module isn't about conditions to provide exemptions. It's about conditions to apply the tax.

So yes, to make it work you have to check all of the roles for which you want the tax applied and leave out the roles for which tax should not be applied. It might also be necessary to apply a [patch](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_product_tax_exempt/issues/3178177) and add a setting.